# SQL Matching many-to-many dates for ID field

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

**Edit**: Fixed Start Date for User 2

I have a list of user ids, each having many start dates and many end dates.

A start date can be recorded many times after the "actual" start date of an "event", same goes for the end date.

The result should be each the first start date and first end date for each user "event"

I hope that makes sense, see the example below.

Thanks!

Assuming the Following tables are given:

**Start Table:**

```
+--------+-------------+
| UserID |  Start      |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 | 2019-01-01  |
|      1 | 2019-01-02  |
|      1 | 2019-01-03  |
|      1 | 2019-04-01  |
|      1 | 2019-04-02  |
|      1 | 2019-04-03  |
|      2 | 2019-06-01  |
|      2 | 2019-06-02  |
|      2 | 2019-10-01  |
|      2 | 2019-10-02  |
+--------+-------------+
```

**End Table:**

```
+--------+------------+
| UserID |  End       |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 2019-03-01 |
|      1 | 2019-03-02 |
|      1 | 2019-03-03 |
|      1 | 2019-05-01 |
|      1 | 2019-05-02 |
|      1 | 2019-05-03 |
|      2 | 2019-08-01 |
|      2 | 2019-08-02 |
|      2 | 2019-12-01 |
|      2 | 2019-12-02 |
+--------+------------+
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| UserID |   Start    |  End       |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 |
|      1 | 2019-04-01 | 2019-05-01 |
|      2 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-08-01 |
|      2 | 2019-10-01 | 2019-12-01 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I agree with your `2019-10-02`

Here is one solution

**Example**

```
Select UserID
      ,[Start]  = min([Start])
      ,[End]
From ( 
        Select A.* 
              ,[End] = (Select min([End]) From EndTable Where UserID=A.UserID  and [End] >= A.Start )
        From  StartTable A
     ) A
Group By UserID,[End]
```

**Returns**

```
UserID  Start       End
1       2019-01-01  2019-03-01
1       2019-04-01  2019-05-01
2       2019-06-01  2019-08-01
2       2019-10-01  2019-12-01
```

Comment: You're right, I fixed the wrong date in the solution. Your answer worked perfectly, thank you!